# how to break out of a typescript map

Tags: typescript, list, dictionary

I have an array `props.values` and an item rendering function `props.renderPreview`.

So far I rendered all of the items on the list using `props.value.map(props.renderPreview)`

Now I wish to have the option to render only the first `n` items, passed in using `props.maxItemsInPreview`. Is there way to add max items to the map, having it stop at the `n+1` iteration?

Comment: Process first two elements: `props.value.slice(0,2).map(props.renderPreview)`

Comment: @captain-yossarian it worked thanks. post it as an asnwer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Array.protottype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
props.value.slice(0,2).map(props.renderPreview)
```

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.